# How to include confidence intervals into ProbabilityScalePlot?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

I use `ProbabilityScalePlot[data, "Weibull"]` to plot measured data and `EstimatedDistribution[data, WeibullDistribution[alpha, beta]]` to estimate the parameters of the two-parameter `Weibull` distribution. Both work fine for me.

But how to estimate and include the confidence intervals into the probability plot?

Comment: You could run a `NonlinearModelFit` to estimate the parameters; this will also provide confidence levels.